Explicit expression of simultaneous resolution of semi-universal deformation of ADE singularity
Denote the semi-universal deformation of ADE singularity by $\mathcal{Y}\to\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}/W$, where $\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}$ is the complex Cartan algebra of root system of type ADE and $W$ is Weyl group. If we pull it back to $\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}$, i.e.
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\mathcal{Y}'@>>>\mathcal{Y} \\
 @VVf'V @VVfV \\
\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}} @>>> \mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}/W
\end{CD}$$
it is known that the locus in $\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}$ of singular fibers is exactly the union of kernels of the roots  denoted by $\bigcup_{\theta} \operatorname{Ker}(\theta)$, i.e. the union of  walls.
My question is:
Is there any explicit description of the type of these singular fibers over points in $\bigcup_{\theta} \operatorname{Ker}(\theta)$?
e.g. we want to know:
(1) Consider the semi-universal deformation of singularity $E_{8}$, then the type of singularities of fibers over $0$ is exactly $E_{8}$, but what the type over the generic point in the kernal of some given root $\theta$?Or more general, the generic points in the intersections of kernal of some roots $\cap_{j=1}^{m}\operatorname{Ker}\theta_{j}$?
(2) Is any subsystem of $E_{8}$, i.e. $A_{k}$, $D_{k}$, $E_{6}$, $E_{7}$, that will occur as the type of some singular fibers?
In 1970 Tyurina gave us explicit expression of simultaneous resolution of semi-universal deformation of A and D singularity in her paper "Resolution of singularities of plane deformations of double rational points", so our question for type A and D is answered by this.
For type $E_{8}$, in 1990 Shioda gave us a stratification of $\mathfrak{h}^{\mathbb{C}}$ with respect to type of singular fibers, but not explicit enough to answer the above my two question. The types $E_{6}$, $E_{7}$ are also unknown for me although Shioda stated that they are similar with $E_{8}$.
If someone know some related results, could you please give me some references, I would also appreciate that anyone could give me some advice to attack these problem.

Tyurina was a woman.

@JasonStarr, re, I was editing to fix a few other issues, so I addressed that, too.  Thanks!

@LSpice, Thanks your edition.

@JasonStarr, sorry for my mistake

Let $\Delta$ be the root system on $\mathfrak h^{\mathbb C}$ of type $ADE$. For $\xi\in\mathfrak h^{\mathbb C}$ let $\Delta(\xi)\subseteq\Delta$ be the set of root $\theta$ with $\theta(\xi)=0$. This is a subroot system of $\Delta$. Let $\Delta(\xi)=\Delta_1\cup\ldots\cup\Delta_s$ be its decomposition into irreducible subroot systems. Then:
The fiber over $\xi$ has exactly $s$ singularities. They are all ADE of type $\Delta_1,\ldots,\Delta_s$.
Since one can choose a set $S\subseteq\Delta$ of simple roots such that $\Delta(\xi)\cap S$ is a set of simple roots of $\Delta(\xi)$, the Dynkin diagram of $\Delta(\xi)$ is a subdiagram of the Dynkin diagram of $\Delta$.
This answers both of your questions:
The fiber over a generic point of $\ker\theta$ has one singularity of type $A_1$.
The fiber over a generic point $\xi$ of $\cap_j\ker\theta_j$ has singularities of type $\Delta(\xi)$ where $\Delta(\xi)=\Delta\cap\langle\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_m\rangle_{\mathbb Q}$.
Every subsystem of $E_8$ occurs as the type of some singular fiber.
Reference: Lemma 1 on page 94 of P. Slodowy: Simple singularities and simple algebraic groups. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 815.

Thank you very much, this is exactly what I am looking for!
